# How can we get array loop in controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, loops

How can we get data from loop of array like we get from ng-repeat use in our views?

I want this:

```
function test() {
   var data = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     var newtest = {
                    text: 'text',
                    class: 'class_name',
                    user_chat_img: "images/noimage.jpg",
                    time_stamp: 'myJSON2'
                  }
                  // console.log('chat history',myJSON);
     data.push(newtest);
   }

   return data;
}

var $scope.message = test();
console.log('message', $scope.message);
```

Now i want to get this array values i.e text,class etc

this give me data in console like this

```
Array[1]
 0: Object
  class: "class_name"
  text: "text",
  time_stamp: "myJSON2",
  user_chat_img: "images/noimage.jpg"
  __proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]
```

How can i get these values in my controller 
i will get these values in my views using ng-repeat 
like

```
ng-repeat={x in message}
and then 
x.class
```

thanks

Comment: I want to these array values in my controller not in my views                                 I want just "How i get these arrays values in my controller "

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Define your function outside controller. This will help you in accessing function as you mentioned.

> ng-repeat="x in message"

Also I have made your function test as a scope function inside the controller.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = test();
        console.log('message', $scope.message);
    });

    function test() {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var newtest = {
                    text: 'text',
                    class: 'class_name',
                    user_chat_img: "images/noimage.jpg",
                    time_stamp: 'myJSON2'
                }
                // console.log('chat history',myJSON);
            data.push(newtest);
        }
        return data;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in message">
        <td>{{x.class}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is good solution this is also working in my views but i want to get this in my controller to use this in another function

Comment: @NazarHussain I have updated the code. Define your function outside controller. This will help you in accessing function as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i think i can not convey my problem to you     I want to use values that send me test function in my controller and then add some more message in that  array and then i have to show   this to my views

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: in this array i get message  and then i send a call to api and that function give some old message Now i have to show all message i  my view

Comment: Can you reproduce it in some fiddle?